# HTML Table Layout - Making a Two Column Table Wrap into Four Columns

Tags: jquery, html-table

Right now I have a simple two column table with z number of rows.  I would like to set a certain number of rows to show, say ten, and then the whole table to wrap to the right of itself but I do not know if that can be done.

Like I mentioned, it is simple html code right now and it looks like:

```
**Word -- Count**
hello -- 1
world -- 16
hi -- 4
wirld -- 1
```

and I would like it to do this:

```
**Word -- Count**
hello -- 1        hi -- 4        etc....
world -- 16       wirld -- 1     etc....
```

Any thoughts on getting this done via JavaScript or JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the table into two or three or four different tables up front, then float them all left. If the width is too narrow they will move to the right place, more or less.

Better would be to do this using something like the flexbox model (http://www.the-haystack.com/2012/01/04/learn-you-a-flexbox/), but unfortunately this isn't really ready for use right now, and has various issues.

Comment: Splitting the table might work, but I have a function already to sort through them and another to load other data.  For the sake of simplicity, I think keeping it in one table might be best.  Any thoughts?